# XML Signature support on Node.js

Tags: xml, node.js, xml-signature

Does anybody know if there is any node.js module to support XML Signature? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should use [xml-crypto](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2012/05/xml-crypto-xml-digital-signature.html) (pure javascript!)